# How can I find out which users are logged in on my computer?

Tags: command-line, users

When I go to shut down the computer every time it says someone is logged in as guest and "do you still want to shut down?". I used the action /var/auth.log but it says permission denied. This is my computer, why won't it let me see who's logged in?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `auth.log` file is located in `/var/log`. Try this: `sudo vi /var/log/auth.log`

Cheers,

Comment: Or one could just `less` it. `sudo` is not needed - OP presumably gets "permission denied" because they are entering a filename as their command and the file has no execute permission (if the file did not exist they would get a "no such file or directory" error)